# How do I get two legends for each color besides having 4 as shown?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm wanting to get two legend labels numatmdebitcardissued and numactive cards, instead of having four for each different date.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: show your report design with the associated chart category and series setup. You can get to this by click on the chart series - it's the small fly-out window

Comment: I added the photo

Comment: Try just removing the series grouping to start with

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your date is in the DebitCardATMDate field and there are four different Series to display.

If the Date and Category were separated, I think it'll will display the way you want. I'll ass**u**me there's a dash in each record.

For the Category, parse out the category from DebitCardATMDate.

```
=Mid(Fields!DebitCardATMDate.Value, InStr(Fields!DebitCardATMDate.Value, "-") + 2, LEN(Fields!DebitCardATMDate.Value))
```

Then for the Series, parse out the date and covert it to a date.

```
=CDATE(LEFT(Fields!DebitCardATMDate.Value, InStr(Fields!DebitCardATMDate.Value, "-") - 2))
```